# List of Lists in C#, problem with indexes

Tags: c#

In C#, I create a list of lists and try to access/modify the elements. There is a problem in that it seems that an operation (e.g. adding a constant) seems to apply not only to the wanted index but to all elements.

Here is the piece of code:

```
List<List<double>> D = new List<List<double>>();
List<double> ttmp = new List<double>(new double[256]);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    D.Add(ttmp);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    D[i][0] = D[i][0] + 1;
}
```

D is a list of 100 lists, each of size 256. It initially contains only zeroes. In the second loop, I ask that the first element of every of the 100 lists be incremented by one.
As a results, the entire "matrix" is filled with ones, i.e. not only `D[0][0]`, `D[1][0]` ... `D[99][0]`, but also `D[0][1]`, `D[0][2]` , etc.
Why is that?

NB: the C++ equivalent with `vector<vector<double>>` works perfectly fine...

Comment: because vectors coping themself on asign ... while list in C# is reference ...

Answer (score 2):

When code is executed, result is not that

> D[0][0], D[1][0] ... D[99][0], but also D[0][1], D[0][2] are modified.

Result is that inner lists have [0] element equal to 100.

Why so? Because you created one list, and added it 100 times into D. But that is the same list - when you modify it, you modify all instances (because this is reference data type).

Change it instead to:

```
        List<List<double>> D = new List<List<double>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            D.Add(new List<double>(new double[256]));
        }

        foreach (var innerList in D)
        {
            innerList[0]++;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!   Quick remark to who voted me down: it is not so clever to do so. To my best knowledge, List is the C# best equivalent of vector in C++. And as mentionned in my post, vectors in C++ do not behave like this, but instead in C++ double indices are "intuitive": D[0][0] = x puts x into the first element of the first element of D...